# Google Sheets Query - Divide by Sum(Col), Error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm doing a simple query but keep getting the error "Add_col_to_group_by_or_agg:Col1".

The formula is

```
=QUERY({L42:N63}, "Select (Col1*Col3)/Sum(Col1)",0)
```

What I'm looking for is just as straightforward as the column of result, multiply, then divide by the sum. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps easier to do without `query()`, like this:

`=arrayformula(L42:L63 * N42:N63 / sum(L42:L63))`

Comment: thanks for that @doubleunary, I actually forgot to mentioned that, the range "L42:N63" is going to be replaced by the result from another query. Something like =QUERY(QUERY({Range}), "Select (Col1*Col3)/Sum(Col1)",0). I was just putting the range in actual cell to test which part I'm getting wrong. So by that I think I've to do it using query. I think the problem came from the "/SUM(Col1)" part, after some testing. But I just not knowledgeable enough to understand what is going wrong here. Thanks

Comment: The policy here is just [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741), so please post your new question in another topic.